# How to get the child nodes of a parent and process it with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<modules>
    <sect>
        <mod name="Weather">
            <minWidth>200</minWidth>
            <minHeight>200</minHeight>
        </mod>
        <mod name="Settings">
            <minWidth>200</minWidth>
            <minHeight>30</minHeight>
        </mod>
    </sect>
    <sect>
        <mod name="Social">
            <minWidth>200</minWidth>
            <minHeight>200</minHeight>
        </mod>
    </sect>
    <sect>
        <mod name="Show">
            <minWidth>200</minWidth>
            <minHeight>200</minHeight>
        </mod>
        <mod name="Puzzle">
            <minWidth>200</minWidth>
            <minHeight>200</minHeight>
        </mod>
    </sect>
</modules>
```

and I want to display every sect node with it's child nodes as list elements with jquery ajax. I tried the following js code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/style/modules/start_page_modules.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('sect').each(function(){
            $("<div></div>").html(function(){
            $(this).find("mod").each(function(){
                var mWidth = $(this).children("mod").find("minWidth").text();
                var mHeight = $(this).children("mod").find("minHeight").text();
                $("<li></li>").css({
                    width: mWidth,
                    height: mHeight
                }).appendTo("sect");
            });
            }).appendTo("#main_content ul");
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
      }
      });
```

and all it does is to append the three `sect` nodes to the `ul` element and nothing else. I want the `mod` nodes to be in their respective divs like so:

```
<div id="sect">
  <li style="width: 200px;height:200px;"></li>
  <li style="width: 200px;height:30px;"></li>
</div>
<div id="sect">
  <li style="width: 200px;height:200px;"></li>
</div> .....and so on
```

Please i need help...

Comment: __IDs must be unique in HTML__ You need to change your strategy for _I want the mod nodes to be in their respective sect divs_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IDs are supposed to be unique, you should use classes instead.
2. `each` returns the current set, not the elements that have been generated in it's callback.
3. You are trying to append the `li` elements to a non-list element which is an invalid markup.

   ```
   $(xml).find('sect').each(function (i, sect) {
       $("<ul class='sect'></ul>").html(function () {
           // `this` here refers to the `ul` ^
           return $(sect).find("mod").map(function () {
               var $mod = $(this);
               var mWidth = $mod.find("minWidth").text();
               var mHeight = $mod.find("minHeight").text();
               return $("<li></li>").css({
                   width: mWidth,
                   height: mHeight
               }); // .text(this.getAttribute('name'));
           }).get();
       }).appendTo("#target");
   });
   ```

The above snippet generates this structure:

```
<ul class="sect">
     <li style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></li>
     <li style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"></li>
</ul>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82ggy/